# HTML special character display

Tags: html, css

When dealing with special characters is there a way to shrink only the special character and shift the position up slightly?

In particular I am trying to use the registration character (little R with circle) but it seems to render at the same size of the font which is not how it should be displayed. It should be shifted up towards the top of the text and the size should be at least half the size.

Is there some sort of escape character that can be inserted right before it so it renders correctly? Or is there a way to use CSS to select only the special character from the text?

The only option I can think of is enclosing each one in a  tag or something similar but I would think that there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for you.  I don't mean to steal from @aaronmallen, I just want you to have a comparison.

**CSS (change ELEMENT to whatever - span most likely):**

```
ELEMENT:after {
    content: '\00AE';
    display: inline; /* if you use on a block element like div */
    zoom: .75;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px; /* because default font size is 16px */
}
```

**HTML would be the `<sup>&reg;</sup>` that was posted already.**

## [See comparison here](http://jsfiddle.net/d47zg/)

Comment: Where's the link? I don't see a link. You should really include a link to a demo.

Comment: I was being sarcastic.

Comment: I like this solution but if the tag is only being used once I don't see the value in adding the css, since html already has a tag for this very purpose.

Comment: It's in case you want to use it over and over.  You could put your logo's class there and not worry about cluttering your HTML with ugly ampersands.  I'm just OCD though :P

Comment: PS - it was really just meant to show the extra option in case you wanted to rely on CSS or something to that effect

Comment: You can do the same thing with `vertic-align: super`: http://jsfiddle.net/d47zg/1/ I would also think the `sup` is more semantically correct. As MDN states: *The HTML Superscript Element (<sup>) defines a span of text that should be displayed, for typographic reasons, higher, and often smaller, than the main span of text.*

Comment: I personally like the css approach since controlling it with a tag enables using the zoom property. If only the <sup> tag is used the text is only shifted up, the size doesn't change.

Comment: @AndyBraham - Not unless you've alternatively styled the `sup` or are using a font that doesn't support `font-size: smaller`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/94VMj/ - updated with comparison of `font-size` options, also normalized CSS.  You know, in case anyone was curious lol

Answer (score 2):

You could use the sup tag.

```
<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
sup {
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

[HTML sup tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/sup.html)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup)

Comment: So in other words you have to add another tag to shift it huh? That's what I was wondering. Thanks aaronmallen...

Comment: Please use the [related W3C reference DOC](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/sup.html) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup).